# как вбить в $html.= код php

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот такой код хочу вбить в `$html.='code';`

```
<div class="titl2">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <p>         
        <?php 
            $map_location = get_field( 'adress' );
            $address = explode( ', ', $map_location['address'] );
            echo $address[0] . ' ' . $address[1];
        ?>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

И как тут же адекватно вынести

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Сделал так, но айди выводит, а класс нет

```
$html .= '<article id="post-'.$post->ID.'" class="'.$post->class.'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Хрустальный шар подсказал, что речь про Wordpress. Метод [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) выводит классы поста (так же как `echo "что-то";`), а не возвращает значение (как `return "что-то";`).

Поэтому для составления строки в переменной, вам нужен родственный метод [`get_post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class). Но он возвращает не форматированную строку, как та, что печатается методом `post_class()`, а возвращает **массив** классов поста. И этот массив ещё надо собрать в строку. Примерно так:

```
$html .= sprintf('<article id="post-%s" class="%s">'
    get_the_ID(),
    implode(',', get_post_class()) // склеит массив через запятую
);
```

То же и к вашему фрагменту кода. Если хотите его поместить в переменную, а не вывести на экран, нужны методы WordPress, которые не выводят, а возвращают значения.

Вместо [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) – [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/). Вместо `echo` – конкатенировать значения к коду. Примерно так:

```
$tmpl = <<<EOFHTML  
<div class="titl2">
    <a href="%s">
        <p>%s</p>
    </a>
</div>
EOFHTML;

$map_location = get_field( 'adress' ); // опечатка? Может, address?
$address = explode( ', ', $map_location['address'] );

$html .= sprintf( $tmpl,
    get_permalink(),
    $address[0] . ' ' . $address[1]
);
```

Тут используется функция возврата форматированной строки [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) и т.н. [heredoc синтакс](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) для задания многострочной строки.

**Альтернативный вариант** – захватывать весь вывод в переменную с помощью буферизации вывода:  [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php) включит запись всего вывода в буфер. После этого делаете обычные `echo` и пр. вывод «на экран» вашего фрагмента – но всё оказывается пока в буфере. И оттуда надо содержание вытащить в переменную: [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-clean.php). Но я бы рекомендовал просто собирать строку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! но тут косяк во втором случае Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)   в первом случае строчка где  get_the_ID(),  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'get_the_ID' (T_STRING)

Comment: Я же вам не рабочий код пишу, чтобы его просто скопировать : )  Исправляйте – лишнюю кавычку уберите в первом случае, замените heredoc на обычную строку во втором.

Comment: да я это понял, сразу же убрал лишнюю кавычку он ругается именно на get_the_ID во втором heredoc вообще убрал и обычную строку делал, все так же

Comment: А вы внутри loop это вызываете? Wordpress свежий, какой версии? См. документацию по функции [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) – может, что-то прояснит.